# SpeechRecognition : AttributeError: type object 'Microphone' has no attribute 'list_working_microphones' on Python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm coding a voice assistant, I use the library SpeechRecognition (3.8.1) and PyAudio (0.2.12)
and I need a working microphone, so I want to use the function "list_working_microphones()" but I get a AttibutError : AttributeError: type object 'Microphone' has no attribute 'list_working_microphones'

```
for device in Microphone.list_working_microphones() : 
        # some code
```

Do you have any suggestions ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you sure you have SpeechRecognition 3.8.1 installed?  The `list_working_microphones()` method did not exist in any previous version.

Comment: yes I have done the command "python -m pip install --upgrade SpeechRecognition"
and I get: Requirement already satisfied: SpeechRecognition in <a file path> (3.8.1)